# The LINQ lambda expression not working

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have the below Linq expression

```
var orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Queue, int>>(
    nullCheckExpression, parameterExpression);

queue = context.Table
    .Join(context.tablea, cq => cq.a, r => r.a, (cq, r) => new { cq, r })
    .Join(context.tableb, s => s.r.b, se => se.b, (s, se) => new { s, se })
    .Join(context.tablec, u => u.s.cq.c, us => us.c, (u, us) => new { u, us })
    .Where(cq => cq.u.s.cq.c == Utilities.Authentication.c)
    .Where(cq => buildStatusOrder.Contains((BuildStatusEnum)cq.u.s.cq.d))
    .OrderBy(o => o.u.se.b)
    .Select(s => new QueueInfo
    {
        x = s.u.c,
        y = s.u.d,
        z = s.u.a
    });

queue = queue.OrderBy(f => orderByLambda);

var concat = queue.GroupBy(e => new { e.x, e.y, e.z })
    .OrderBy(v => v.FirstOrDefault().segmentID)
    .ToList()
    .Select(ss => new QueueInfo
    {
        x = ss.x,
        y = ss.y,
        z = ss.z,
    })
    .AsQueryable();
```

I am getting below error in `concat`

```
The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

What went wrong in my code?

Comment: You still did not fix as Habib suggested. That's the line that causes error.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
queue = queue.OrderBy(f => orderByLambda);
```

Use:

```
queue = queue.OrderBy(orderByLambda);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two notes on your code:

1. LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework) wants to translate your query into SQL, so it can only do operations that it knows how to translate. For example, you can't use most common LINQ collection methods such as `Contains`, etc.
2. You have defined a lambda object, but not what the actual expression *does*, to use for sorting - or at least, you haven't shown us what `nullCheckExpression` and `parameterExpression` are. In general, this is not how you would sort LINQ to Entities anyway - it should be something like `queue.OrderBy(f => f.x).ThenBy(f => f.y);` - you have to define which fields from your select are actually used for the sort. (See point number 1)